# how to import multiple namespaces properly

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

I am very new to PHP namespaces and I have a question:

If we import multiple namespaces with the 'use' command, shouldn't we run into issues? 
I have been reading through this post http://www.sitepoint.com/php-namespaces-import-alias-resolution/, and in the section about Namespace Importing, it says that you still need to have a qualified prefix next to a function (ie: Lib2), but when looking at some Symfony 2 example files, I don't see that happening.
How is namespacing solving (in the example file below) solving name conflicts?

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\ContactType;

// these import the "@Route" and "@Template" annotations
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DemoController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="_demo")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return array();
}

/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
 * @Template()
 */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    return array('name' => $name);
}

/**
 * @Route("/contact", name="_demo_contact")
 * @Template()
 */
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $mailer = $this->get('mailer');

        // .. setup a message and send it
        // http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email.html

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set('notice', 'Message sent!');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('_demo'));
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
}
```

Comment: Alias are only required in case of conflict. Many use are not a prblem. In case of conflict, simply add an alias.

Answer (score 2):

I think the misunderstanding comes from the post's filenames. keep in mind:

- DefaultController.php with `namespace Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller/` will be included with `use Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller/DefaultController`
- DefaultController2.php with `namespace Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller2/` will be included with `use Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller2/DefaultController2`

To have a conflict you'd need to include two files named DefaultController.php

- DefaultController.php with `namespace Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller`
- DefaultController.php with `namespace Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller2`

And would then need an alias as pointed out by Kevin

- DefaultController.php with `namespace Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller` 
  => `use Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller/DefaultController`
- DefaultController.php with `namespace Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller2` 
  => `use Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller2/DefaultController as DefaultController2`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best way to explain this is to work backwards from the namespace resolution.

Say you have a line like the following:

```
$newFoo = new Foo();
```

PHP will look through the current symbol table for the class Foo. That symbol table includes the current namespace and any imported (use) namespaces (as well as built-in PHP symbols).

For example, say class Foo is declared in Foo.php:

```
<?php //Baz/Foo.php
namespace Baz\Foo;

class Foo{}
```

If you were working in Bar.php, you could reference the following:

```
<?php //Baz/Bar.php
namespace Baz\Bar;
use Baz\Foo;
//The following lines are equivalent
$newFoo = new Foo\Foo(); //Local namespace
$newFoo = new \Baz\Foo\Foo(); //Fully qualified namespace
```

You could also reference the Foo class directly in your use, rather than referencing the Foo namespace.

```
<?php //Baz/Bar.php
namespace Baz\Bar;
use Baz\Foo\Foo;
//The following lines are equivalent
$newFoo = new Foo(); //Local namespace
//$newFoo = new Foo\Foo(); //This will fail, as the symbol Foo is a class, not a namespace
$newFoo = new \Baz\Foo\Foo(); //Fully qualified namespace still works.
```

If you wanted to reference both the Namespace and the Class Foo directly, you'd need to resolve the conflict with an Alias.

```
<?php //Baz/Bar.php
namespace Baz\Bar;
use Baz\Foo;
use Baz\Foo\Foo as FooClass;
//The following lines are equivalent
$newFoo = new FooClass(); //Notice the new aliased symbol.
$newFoo = new Foo\Foo(); //This works now.
$newFoo = new \Baz\Foo\Foo(); //Fully qualified namespace still works.
//$newFoo = new \Baz\Foo\FooClass(); //This will fail, aliases don't work for fully qualified names.
```

Also, say, in addition to your Baz/Foo.php file, you have a Bar/Foo.php file as such:

```
<?php //Bar/Foo.php
namespace Bar\Foo;

class Foo{}
```

If you wanted to reference both namespaces locally, you'll need aliases to resolve the name conflict:

```
<?php //Baz/Bar.php
namespace Baz\Bar;
use Baz\Foo as Foo1;
use Baz\Foo\Foo as Foo1Class;
use Bar\Foo as Foo2;
use Bar\Foo\Foo as Foo2Class;
//The following lines are equivalent, referencing Baz\Foo\Foo
$newBazFoo = new Foo1Class(); //Object alias.
$newBazFoo = new Foo1\Foo();  //Namespace alias.
$newBazFoo = new \Baz\Foo\Foo(); //Fully qualified namespaces don't need any aliases.
//The following lines are equivalent, referencing Bar\Foo\Foo
$newBarFoo = new Foo2Class(); //Object alias.
$newBarFoo = new Foo2\Foo();  //Namespace alias.
$newBarFoo = new \Bar\Foo\Foo(); //Fully qualified namespaces don't need any aliases.
```

In addition to importing the Namespace with the use statement, you will also need to include the file containing that namespace. This can be done manually with require_once(), but is normally handled automatically by an autoloader.

See [Symfony Class Loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/introduction.html) for more details.

Hope that helps.